# ITS-90 Tempature coefficents for a standard PT100 385 RTD

Tags: resistance, calibration, rtd

I'm currently using the ITS-90 formula to convert a resistance of an RTD to a temperature. I got the coefficients from the manufacturers calibration sheet. The problem is I have another probe that I don't have the ITS-90 coefficients for. Is there a standard theoretical set of coefficients that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. RTDs are standardized by IEC-751 and EN 60751.

[IEC-751 tabular values from Thermometrics](http://www.thermometricscorp.com/acstan.html)

[EN 60751 formulas from Omega engineering](https://www.omega.com/techref/pdf/z251.pdf)